# Search Refinements: Some dropdowns displaying number instead of text

Tags: search, dropdown, refiner

I have a large document library that has a bunch of dropdown fields that I'm using as refinements.  The refinements should come back as:

ANIMALS

Cat
Dog
Mouse

But what I'm seeing is that it's coming back like this:

ANIMALS

Cat
Dog
1
Mouse
2

I inspected the field value, and the values are stored as:

1;#Dog

And inspecting the documents that are showing up as the numbers in the refinements, they appear to be normal.  Re-saving doesn't help.  It looks like there's only a small number of documents it's happening to (~3%).  And on the documents, of 4 dropdown values, it's not always all of the dropdown values are appearing as numbers, it's sometimes mixed: (1, 4, Dog, Foo).

Has anybody seen anything like this?  Any idea what's going on or how best to clean this up?

Comment: Did you switch column types from Choice to Lookup (or vice versa)?

Comment: Hmm...I inherited the site so that's a definite possibility.  So you're thinking anything marked with the Choice would keep it's integer value...I can see that.  I think I'm gonna write a powershell script to re-save all the list items, and I'll post with my results!

Comment: By the way, re-saving all of the files via a powershell script did the trick!

Comment: Do you want to add that information as an answer and accept it? Might be helpful for other people in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I wound up saving all of the items in the site using the following script, and that did the trick.

```
$totalCount = 0

$web = Get-SPWeb "http://dev.site.com"

$list = $web.Lists["Documents"]

foreach ($listItem in $list.Items)
{
    $listItem.Update()
    $totalCount++
    Write-Host "Item saved: " $totalCount
}

Write-Host "Total Items Updated = " $totalCount

$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Charlie Holland's article: "[Building a custom refinement filter generator for SharePoint 2010](http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2011/03.aspx)"

It contains a step-by-step guide, and even has the source code available as a Codeplex project.

Comment: Shaun: to add more value to your answer, please try and be more verbose when answering. :-)